# PluralizingTableNameConvention throwing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

I am writing my first MVC program, and following along with the online tutorials. I've hit one point where I'm getting an error however, and I can't seem to find the right word to fix it. The class below uses a type of "PluralizingTableNameConvention" in order to prevent the DB from using name plurals. That type is throwing an error however (unknown type). I don't know if I'm missing a namespace, or if the type has been deprecated and I need to use a different one? Any ideas?

namespace Auction.Models
{
    public class AuctionContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet Categories { get; set; }

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following namespace

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
```